# how to undistort a jpeg image file using distortion coefficients?

Tags: java, opencv

I have a distorted snapshot of my webcam. as jpeg file, intrinsic matrix and distortion coefficients:-

```
matrix intrisic matrix
      (1137.0919189453125,0.0,383.99273681640625)
      (0.0,264.17974853515625,312.74951171875)
      (0.0,0.0,1.0)

matrix distortion :-
    (-0.26913660764694214)
    (0.22259517014026642)
    (-0.0928017795085907)
    (0.26249778270721436)
```

I don't know how to load these distortion coefficients in CvMat in order to 
obtain undistorted image using these distortion coefficients.
also, I want to do this using javacv only.

edit:-
also, i know the function

```
IplImage mapx=cvCreateImage(cvSize(src_img),IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
IplImage mapy=cvCreateImage(cvSize(src_img),IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);

cvInitUndistortMap(CvMat intrinsic,CvMat distortion, IplImage mapx, IplImage mapy); 
cvRemap(IplImage tm,IplImage src,IplImage mapx,IplImage mapy,CV_INTER_LINEAR|CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS,cvScalarAll(0));
```

but i don't know how to initialize respective cvMats for intrinsic matrix and distortion coefficient.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why not use [`cv::undistort`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)?

It takes your matrices as its parameters.

`void undistort(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, const Mat& cameraMatrix, const Mat& distCoeffs, const Mat& newCameraMatrix=Mat())`

The `src` matrix is your image.

The `dst` matrix is the undistorted image.

The `cameraMatrix` is your intrinsic matrix.

The `distCoeffs` matrix is your distortion matrix.

To quote from the documentation:

> The particular subset of the source image that will be visible in the
>   corrected image can be regulated by `newCameraMatrix` . You can use
>   GetOptimalNewCameraMatrix to compute the appropriate `newCameraMatrix` ,
>   depending on your requirements.

---

OK. I just found the answer to your comment.... I think.

`public static native void cvUndistortPoints(CvMat src, CvMat dst, CvMat camera_matrix,
            CvMat dist_coeffs, CvMat R/*=null*/, CvMat P/*=null*/);`
You can find this in http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/educationalrobots/name/audet/samuel/javacv/jna/cv.java.htm.

This is actually in **imgproc**.

Just make the last two parameters `null`.

---

The second part - initializing a CvMat - is tougher than it looks, because you have to mess around with pointers if you want to do it elegantly, and I forget how to use JNA Pointers :)

So here's an alternate solution:
Use this constructor `public static CvMat create(int rows, int cols, int type);`

So, for your matrix, you would have three rows and three columns.

Your type would be one of the types in cxcore.java, probably `CV_64FC1`, which is the single-channel `double` type. Otherwise, if you're using `float`s, it would be `CV_32FC1`.

Then you would set the values, one by one, by using:
`opencv_core.cvSet2D(matrix, i, j, value);`
Where `i` is row and `j` is column!

Any more questions?

Cheerio!

Comment: @LokeshKumar I think that I found the method. I edited the question to include it.

Comment: @LokeshKumar By "but i don't know how to initialize respective cvMats for intrinsic matrix and distortion coefficient," do you mean that you don't know how to initialize the `cvMat` data structure, or that you don't know how to get the actual values?

Comment: yeah.. i don't know how to initialize the cvMat data structure using above intrinsic and distortion coefficients values!!

Comment: @LokeshKumar Finally finished my edit after searching through tons of source code!

Comment: i think one can load values in CvMat object..  simply by using cvmatObj.put(i,j,value); //:-)